# Xcode Core Data Termination Issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Whenever I set a Core Data relationship that I don't want to have an inverse, Xcode quits.  This does not seem normal.  I am getting so frustrated.  Being new to CoreData, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed not normal. You should report a bug for that on http://bugreport.apple.com. BTW, which version of Xcode? I haven't seen this with 4.4/4.5 lately.

Now, relationships without an inverse are not recommended. If you truly do not need an inverse, you better have to include one anyway with a specific name so you know is it here just to please Core Data (like, `<yourrelationship>_topleasecoredata` ;). Relationships without an inverse are like an open bag of hurts. You do not know what will jump out of the bag, but sooner than later something will hurt you. An inverse costs you almost nothing.

Comment: It is version 4.3.3. I would report the bug, but I deleted the Data Model file and started over (strangely it has not fully replicated the same issue).  I went ahead and changed it to have inverses. It is not consistent, so I am unsure exactly how to explain how to replicate in the bug reports. I have noticed that CoreData has been very glitchy in this version. What would you recommend?